# VB not stopping at exceptions

Tags: vb.net, exception

I like VB.Net, but there is something that is driving me nuts.  Too many times when an exception occurs, it simply continues somewhere else, usually by exiting the sub or function, but otherwise keeps on rolling.  As an example, I was using Asc() instead of AscW().  It didn't throw an exception, it just left the function as if a Return was executed. Meanwhile I'm leaving red dot stop points all over like it has chicken pox trying to figure out what is causing it.

Is there a setting that can be used to used to actually cause VB to stop and give a line number?

Comment: Are you using some VB legacy mumbo jumbo like `On Error Resume Next`? Also, try setting DEBUG -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> Thrown and see if it makes any difference. Is your exception thrown in the Load method of a Form? These are sometimes swallowed (depending on your system).

Answer (score 0):

Try catch statements will help you out greatly.

Take a read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Try..Catch..Finally statement. E.g. The ex.string will put the exception into a string in the message and tell you the vb line.

```
Try 

'code here

Catch ex as Exception 
MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. " & ex.ToString, "Data Error ")

End Try
```